# PHP time confusion with if statements

Tags: php, if-statement, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm sure this is a very obvious question however I am really bad at working with timestamps and comparing them to in if statements.

What I am trying to do is define if a staff member has been on the team for
`0-5 months` `6-11 months` `12-17 months` and `18+ months`

And that is just meant to change the class of the table so

0-5 months is RED

6-11 months is ORANGE

12-17 months is BLUE

18+ months is GREEN

Here's my code so far, I'm sure it's completely wrong. The `$dataResult['hire_date']` is the `timestamp` when they were hired.

```
$milestone6 = strtotime("6 months ago");
$milestone12 = strtotime("12 months ago");
$milestone18 = strtotime("18 months ago");

if($dataResult['hire_date'] < $milestone6) {
    //red?
} elseif($dataResult['hire_date'] < $milestone12) {
    //orange?
} elseif($dataResult['hire_date'] < $milestone18) {
    //blue?
} else {
   //green?
}
```

Again thank you. It does not matter what order the if statements are in. Will mark as answered when I can.

Comment: Well, in my opinion you shouldn't post code that you are sure is completely wrong. Do you want somebody else to do all the work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$milestone6 = strtotime("6 months ago");
$milestone12 = strtotime("12 months ago");
$milestone18 = strtotime("18 months ago");

$dataResult['hire_date'] = strtotime( '27-05-2015' );

if($dataResult['hire_date'] > $milestone6) {
    echo 'red';
} elseif($dataResult['hire_date'] > $milestone12 ) {
    echo 'orange';
} elseif($dataResult['hire_date'] > $milestone18 ) {
    echo 'blue';
} else {
    echo 'green';
}
```

You are both mixing up time values the equation should go the other way around, try it ;)

Comment: See I don't think this is working the way it should either. Check out the screenshot http://prntscr.com/97j6nv

Comment: Hey remove the edit, the first answer worked well - my mistake as I made an error with the milestone18 string. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

```
$milestone6 = strtotime("6 months ago");
$milestone12 = strtotime("12 months ago");
$milestone18 = strtotime("18 months ago");

if($dataResult['hire_date'] < $milestone6) {
    //red?
    //0-5 months is RED
} elseif($dataResult['hire_date'] < $milestone12 && $dataResult['hire_date'] >= $milestone6) {
    //orange?
    //6-11 months is ORANGE
} elseif($dataResult['hire_date'] < $milestone18 && $dataResult['hire_date'] >= $milestone12) {
    //blue?
    //12-17 months is BLUE
} else {
   //green?
   //18+ months is GREEN
}
```

Comment: This seems to make `0-5 green` `6-11 red` and `12-18 red` and `18+ red`

Comment: `$milestone18` has what value? if `$milestone18` has value of 18 and you need 17 then I will edit code above @Jayden

Comment: Just `strtotime("18 months ago")` whatever that comes out, is that right?

Comment: are you sure that `strtotime("18 months ago")` will give you value of 19 instead of 18? @Jayden

Comment: I'm not sure of anything I thought `strtotime("18 months ago")` just gives me the timestamp of whatever the timestamp was 18 months ago to this date?

Comment: Cause the second code you posted is doing the same thing

Comment: Can you echo values of all $milestone vars @Jayden